# Chi Square "array size"

Tags: statistics

Hi I have a simple question. I don't understand if a chi square test needs to have an initial square array with the same number of rows and columns :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3lyW.png)

Or if the number of rows and columns can be different.

My second question is : what do the rows represent? (category, ...) and what do the columns represent?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are asking about a chi-squared test of independence
of two categorical variables. There is no reason that the two
categorical variables must have the same number of levels.

For example, if one categorical variable is Profession, it might have five different
levels. (Perhaps a couple of the categories might be 'Educator'
and 'Health Care Professional'.) And if the other categorical variable is political Party Affiliation, it
might have three levels. (In the US, the categories might be
'Republican', 'Democratic', and 'Independent'.) So there would be $5 \times 3$ 'cells'
in the two-way table. (I believe that the $10 \times 10$ grid
shown in your link is just an illustration.)

*Note:* One restriction is that the number of cells should not be so
large and the number of subjects so small that the expected counts for some of the cells become less than about 5. If there a large
proportion of the cells have relatively small expected counts, then
the distribution of the chi-squared statistic might not have
an approximately chi-squared distribution.